# Changes in dll on converting web application from vs 2008 to 2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

I want to use an ASP.NET web application which was built using visual studio 2008 to 2013. will keep the .net framework to 3.5.

My concern is: There will be changes to `.csproj` and `.sln` after opening the project in 2013 but what about the dll to be deployed. would i need to update the hosting environment to 4.0 or any dependency upgrade?

Comment: Done it 5 times. Never a problem. Since you keep framework 3.5 - no issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csproj and sln files will indeed be upgraded, but that has no bearing on the output of compilation.

As long as you continue to build for .NET 3.5, there shouldn't be any additional requirements to deploy your application. One thing to keep in mind is that VS2008 web deploy projects and database projects have been deprecated, and no upgrade path for those exists. So be careful if you're using either of those.

The safest approach for you will be to test the upgrade. Install VS2013, which runs side-by-side with VS2008. Open up the old solution, let VS update it, then do a test deployment. If there's a problem, just revert the change to whatever your last source controlled version is.